# DTD, #REQUIRED, #IMPLIED, Example

Tags: xml, dtd

I have a DTD-file,this is a part of it.It's written lv id ID #IMPLIED.
As definition for #REQUIRED stays: "Elements can have zero or more attributes."That makes the code automatically correct,but could #IMPLIED be replaced with #REQUIRED,because the element here have already one attribute and no zero attributes,or I miss something?

```
<!ELEMENT lv (title, subtitle?, length, content, abstract)>
<!ATTLIST lv id ID #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT subtitle (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT abstract (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT length EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST length value CDATA #REQUIRED
          unit (sws| h| min) "sws">
```

This is the associated XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet href="lv.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
    <!DOCTYPE lv SYSTEM "lehre.dtd">
    <lv id="wip2">
      <title>WI-Praktikum 2</title>
      <subtitle>Verarbeitung strukturierter Daten</subtitle>
      <length value="2" unit="sws"/>
      <content>
        <topic>Grundlagen</topic>
        <topic>Grammatiken</topic>
        <topic>SAX</topic>
      </content>
      <abstract>
      Der Kurs vermittelt den Aufbau und die Verarbeitung von XML-Dokumenten.
      Als Programmiersprachen kommen Java, Python und XSLT zum Einsatz.
      </abstract>
    </lv>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but yes you can change `#IMPLIED` to `#REQUIRED` in the attribute declaration for the attribute `id` on the element `li`.

The attribute `id` is the type `ID` so it has to have a default of either `#IMPLIED` or `#REQUIRED`. Which one is up to you.

You must also have only one `ID` type attribute declared for an element, but your DTD already satisfies that requirement so nothing to worry about there.

See the spec ([3.3 Attribute-List Declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttlistDecl)) for more info.

Comment: @DianaPapukchieva - You're very welcome. If this answers your question sufficiently, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark next to it.